# Unity 2D For Mobile:- Player Getting Stuck While moving Using Buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Left and Right button for my Character or Player Movement Horizontally. Everything Works Fine But Suddenly The Character gets Stuck in Some Direction. The Other Direction Works Well But After Sometime Vice Versa Happens (The Other Direction Gets Stuck And Other Get Released)

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharMovement : MonoBehaviour
{  private float HorizontalMove;
private float speed  = 6f;
   private bool moveleft;
   private bool moveRight; 
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
   private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        moveleft = false;
        moveRight = false;
    }

    
   private void Update()
    { 
         movement();
    }
    public void PointerLeftDown(){
        moveleft = true;
    }
    public void PointerLeftUp(){
        moveleft = false;
    }
    public void PointerRightDown(){
        moveRight = true;
    }
    public void PointerRightUp(){
        moveRight = false;
    }
    private void movement(){
        if(moveleft){
            HorizontalMove = -speed;
        }
        else if (moveRight){
            HorizontalMove = speed;
        }
        else {
            HorizontalMove = 0f;
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (HorizontalMove , rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Player Movement

Comment: how are we supposed to know from this why it gets stuck? in your last post this exact code was working - you need to work out what you changed if its behavior has changed

Comment: There is a timer working and you a getting multiple events occurring within on timer event.  Try adding code like this : public void PointerLeftDown(){
        moveRight = false; moveleft = true;
    } and public void PointerRightDown(){
        moveleft = false; moveRight = true;
    }

Comment: The main problem is tilemap collider. it getting stuck in edges. i have added a composite collider and checked use composite bool now its fine. is there any way without composite collider